# Installing GDAL on Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: gdal, pip, google-cloud

I am having trouble installing GDAL on Google Cloud Datalab. When I run:

```
!pip install gdal
```

I get the following error

```
Collecting gdal
Using cached GDAL-2.2.4.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info
creating pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info
writing pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg- 
info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/GDAL.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-umhRKK/gdal/setup.py", line 342, in <module>
    **extra )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", 
  line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in 
  run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 278, in run
    self.find_sources()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 293, in find_sources
    mm.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 524, in run
    self.add_defaults()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 560, in add_defaults
    sdist.add_defaults(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
    self._add_defaults_ext()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
    build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-umhRKK/gdal/setup.py", line 217, in finalize_options
    self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-umhRKK/gdal/setup.py", line 191, in get_gdal_config
    return fetch_config(option)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-umhRKK/gdal/setup.py", line 144, in fetch_config
    raise gdal_config_error, e""")
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
__main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-umhRKK/gdal/
```

Same thing goes for :

```
!pip install gdal==2.2
```

or :

```
!pip install python-gdal
```

and a few other similar commands I have tried. The fix I discovered which was to update the setup-tools still gives me this problem after updating it. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following tutorial. It guides you to installation with `apt-get` : 
http://www.acgeospatial.co.uk/colaboratory-notebooks-and-gdal/